# Finding the maximum value of $\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$ of a vector field

Tags: calculus, integration, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I'm stuck with trying to find the maximum value for $\oint_C \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{r}$ of the vector field $\vec{F}=\langle5z, x, y \rangle$ where $C$ is a simple closed curve in the plane $2x+3y+z=7$.

I don't really know how to start with a problem like this, my guess on how to start would be to use Stoke's Theorem, but I don't know how I'd proceed. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're right to want to use Stokes's Theorem. If $C$ is encloses the region $R$ in the plane $2x+3y+z=7$, with outward normal $\vec n = (2,3,1)/\sqrt{14}$, then 
$$\int_C \vec F\cdot d\vec r = \iint_R (\text{curl } \vec F\cdot\vec n)dA = \frac{18}{\sqrt{14}}\text{area}(R).$$
Can this ever have a maximum value?